# How can I track down back issues of a family history newsletter from the 1980's?

Tags: research-methods

When I started asking my parents about family history in 2008, my mother gave me a copy of a "Burbank Family News" newsletter of the Burbank-Burbanck family edited by John R. Burbank in St. Albans, Vermont. I only have one issue, #21 from January 1986. It was a long shot, but I tried writing to the return address requesting back issues, with no response. How can I track down back issues of a family history newsletter possibly sent by an individual by mail during the 1980's? Is it likely that there are copies of this newsletter at a library or genealogical society? Where should I look next?

Comment: Ben,
If you contact me privately I can provide you with info that can help you get in touch with the family of John R. Burbank but don't want to post it publicly. Andy
agh3rd@aol.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **FamilySearch Catalog.** The FamilySearch Catalog has an entry for John R. Burbank's "[Burbank family news : a newsletter of the Burbank - Burbanck family in America.](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/show?uri=http://catalog-search-api:8080/www-catalogapi-webservice/item/348357)." The catalog entry reports this newsletter was continued as the "Burbank Banner."
- **WeRelate, source list entry**. An entry for this newsletter appears in the WeRelate listing of sources, "[Burbank, John R. Burbank Family News : A Newsletter of the Burbank - Burbanck Family in America](http://www.werelate.org/wiki/Source:Burbank,_John_R._Burbank_Family_News_:_A_Newsletter_of_the_Burbank_-_Burbanck_Family_in_America)."

But wait, there's more.

- **Contact John Burbank**. As I see [bstpierre has also found](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1771/7), John Burbank, who seems one and the same, editor of the newsletter(s), responded to an inquiry about "Burbank Family News" on Genforum. John Burbank to Jean Penn, "[Re: Burbank family motto](http://genforum.genealogy.com/burbank/messages/268.html)," message post of 8 October 2006. Clicking on John's user name in the GenForum post bring up an e-mail address. Checking his "User's Message Posting History," returns yet more recent posts by John, **through early 2012**.

I can't know whether that registered e-mail address is valid, but perhaps with a little fiddling about his current posts and interests, you will be able to reach the editor himself!

Answer (score 6):

Searching for "John R. Burbank" in Vermont turns up several hits with him as a researcher. If he is the same "Rev. John R. Burbank", [he was performing funeral services](http://www.addisonindependent.com/obituaries?page=143) as recently as 2008 in Monkton, VT. I would try to find his church or other current contact info -- perhaps in Monkton or Bristol (both in Addison County) -- and ask him directly.

You might also try searching for Internet postings like [this one](http://genforum.genealogy.com/burbank/messages/373.html) to contact him via email. (Posts as recent as Feb 2012.)

Comment: Good find! The latter link sure increases the likelihood that his e-mail address is current.